# ios googlemaps apiで現在地ボタンが稼働しません。仕様変更がありましたか？

Tags: google-maps

今まで動いていたアプリを、新しいxcodeとsdkでコンパイルしたら、
googlemaps apiで表示している地図上の現在地ボタンが稼働しなくなりました。
何か仕様変更があったのでしょうか？

現在地ボタンの表示は、objective-c内で以下のコードで行なっています。

```c
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
```

googlemaps sdk のバージョンは、2.7.0、
xcodeのバージョンは、9.3.1 です。

google map アプリでは現在地ボタンは機能しています。

また、アプリ内では、UITableView → UITableView → 地図　と画面遷移させているのですが、テーブルビュー間の画面遷移がとても遅くなってしまいました。
これにつきましても、何か思い当たるような原因をご存知でしたらご教授願いたいと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

単純なサンプルプログラムを作ってみて、アプリ名.plistにセキュリティ関連のキーを追加したら稼働しましたので、動かない古いPGMは細部を見直したり、プロジェクトから作り直すかしてみます。